# Javascript modal - disable scroll for body but enable for modal with css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created this html code for my modal window

```js
$("button").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".wrap-fadeOut").fadeIn(800);
  $('html').css('overflow', 'hidden');
  $('body').bind('touchmove', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  display: block;
}
.wrap-fadeOut {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}
.modal {
  margin: 2em auto;
  background: white;
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Show modal</button>
<div class="wrap-fadeOut">
<div class="modal">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
<img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/90/c1/33/90c133d504c043c904215de79fc3c892.jpg" alt="">
<img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/90/c1/33/90c133d504c043c904215de79fc3c892.jpg" alt="">
<a href="#" class="button closeModal">Button</a>
</div>
</div>
```

What I should do for disable scrolling of body, but remain scrolling of .modal? I prefer CSS solution, but jQuery/javascript is as well welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1**

On the invoke of your modal, add `overflow-y: hidden` to your `body`.

```
$("button").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".wrap-fadeOut").fadeIn(800);
  $('body').css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
  $('body').bind('touchmove', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
  });
});
```

And then you need to remove the `overflow-y` property from `body` on closing of the modal.

```
$(".closeModal").click(function() {
    $('body').css('overflow-y', 'auto');
    $(".wrap-fadeOut").fadeOut(800);
});
```

**Method 2**

Or, else you can create a css class like

```
.hideScroll {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

and add the css class to the body on modal open and remove it on modal close.

```
$("button").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".wrap-fadeOut").fadeIn(800);
  $('body').addClass("hideScroll");
  $('body').bind('touchmove', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
  });
});

$(".closeModal").click(function() {
  $('body').removeClass("hideScroll");
  $(".wrap-fadeOut").fadeOut(800);
});
```

**NOTE**: *To enable scrolling on the modal, give it a fixed height & provide `overflow-y: auto`*

```
.modal {
  height: 300px; /* customise as per the height required */
  overflow-y: auto
}
```

Comment: But this is the solution for closing the modal. I need to scroll .modal when is displayed.

Comment: To enable scroll on a particular container, you have to have a fixed `height` or `max-height` which tells the browser to enable scroll after a particular value. Or else, if the height of your modal is more than the height of the screen, scrollbar will come automatically due to the `overflow-y: auto`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this css in model class

```
.model{
    max-height: calc(100vh - 210px);
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

You can add whatever max height you need to show model div... you can also give 600px height and overflow-y:auto to model div rest of all your code is fine.

Answer (score 0):

checkout this snippet

```js
$("button").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".wrap-fadeOut").fadeIn(800);
  $('html').css('overflow', 'hidden');
  $('body').bind('touchmove', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
  });
});


$(".closeModal").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('html').css('overflow', 'auto');
  $(".wrap-fadeOut").fadeOut(800);
});
```

```css
img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.wrap-fadeOut {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}
.modal {
  margin: 2em auto;
  background: white;
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 1em;
  overflow-x: auto;
  height: 90%;
}
.content {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Show modal</button>

<div class="content">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
</div>

<div class="wrap-fadeOut">
<div class="modal">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
<img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/90/c1/33/90c133d504c043c904215de79fc3c892.jpg" alt="">
<img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/90/c1/33/90c133d504c043c904215de79fc3c892.jpg" alt="">
<a href="#" class="button closeModal">Button</a>
</div>
</div>
```